# Using the WebSocket module with JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm using WebSocket for the first time for a project and I keep getting a syntax error from the HTML file that runs the JavaScript file where the bulk of the code is. The relevant code is as follows:

**client.js**

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket('wss://example.com');

//rest of code
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type='module' src="./websocket.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The exact error message I got was "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module", which originated from the HTML file.

I added the `type='module'` part based on an answer to a similar question but I still got the same error message. I believe the cause is to do with how I wrote the WebSocket import in one of the files, potentially which part(s) of the WebSocket library I need to include, but my inexperience with JavaScript is preventing me from identifying a fix.

Comment: The code you shared in `client.js` is server-side code, meant to run in Node. If you want to do client-side websocket, you don't need to import anything.

Comment: Hi Rhiannon. Please check this jsFiddle as an example?
https://jsfiddle.net/bmknight/RqbYB/

Comment: @gre_gor: That duplicate has no accepted or upvoted answer, which means it cannot be used as a dupe closure post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebSocket without import ws module.
Web Browser supports WebSocket object as default.
I wrote code below.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.144.142:8000");

ws.onopen = () => { console.log("WebSocket connected."); };
```